# python twitter api tweet timestamp convert from UTC to EST

Tags: python, api, twitter, time, tweets

Using the twitter api for python, I need to get the timestamp of the tweet. I did that. I just need to know how to convert it from UTC to EST.

here is the code:

```
def main():
    twitter = Twitter(auth=OAuth('....'))
    tweet = twitter.statuses.user_timeline.snl()
    tweet_datetime = tweet[0]['created_at']
    print tweet_datetime 


>>> main()
>>> Tue Jun 18 22:23:22 +0000 2013
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) module:

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime


eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
utc = timezone('UTC')

created_at = datetime.strptime(tweet[0]['created_at'], '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
utc_created_at = utc.localize(created_at)
print utc_created_at
est_created_at = utc_created_at.astimezone(eastern)
print est_created_at
```

prints:

```
2013-06-18 22:23:22+00:00
2013-06-18 18:23:22-04:00
```

Hope that helps.